# ResourceBundle not found at different PC

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, resourcebundle

I have a Servlet project with JSP to which i made a `i18n`. 
My `resources.properties` files are in `src/main/resources/` and all working on my PC (Windows 10). 
I commited update to git, my friend fetched it, and it is not working. The resource bundle seems like not found. He has bundle var names instead of values.

In JSP i do:
At the top `<fmt:setBundle basename="resources"/>` (resources is the bundle name),
and every value replace with `<fmt:message key="leftbar.librarian"/>`
When i want to change languages from JSP i made:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${cookie.get('language').value == 'ru'}">
        <fmt:setLocale value='ru' scope="session"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <fmt:setLocale value='en' scope="session"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<fmt:setBundle basename="resources"/>
```

and via JS i set cookies from click on button. It is all working on my PC. At three another PC the bundle is not loaded (but without errors).

So, how i should define the bundle in Java, so others can get it?

P.S. I am not used Java code to configure it. All in JSP. But ready to refactor if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Tomcat not found recources from /resources path. So i had to move bundle to root. Now projects start on all PC`s